# Lowest starting row indices for minimum 2 consecutive non-zero values per column

Tags: matlab, matrix

Considering the sample matrix:

```
A =
     0     0     0     0    -4     3
     0     2     1     0     0     0
     0     5     0     8     7     0
     0     9    10     3     1     2
```

I want to find the lowest starting locations (row indices) for each column of `A` where minimum 2 consecutive non-zero values are found. The output would look like this:

```
Output = [0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0]
```

The `0`'s in the output indicate that the condition of `minimum 2 consecutive non-zero values` doesn't stand.

Also, could this be generalized to a case of finding starting indices of minimum `N` consecutive non-zero values?

Comment: How can location be zero in MATLAB, its 1-based indexing. Also, it would be better if you can explain how the output comes.

Comment: I didn't say the location would be zero. I only said if that if my condition doesn't stand, set it to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Minimum 2 consecutive non-zero values case**

```
%// Mask of non-zeros in input, A
mask = A~=0

%// Find starting row indices alongwith boolean valid flags for minimum two 
%// consecutive nonzeros in each column
[valid,idx] = max(mask(1:end-1,:) & mask(2:end,:),[],1)

%// Use the valid flags to set invalid row indices to zeros
out = idx.*valid
```

Sample run -

```
A =
     0     0     0     0    -4     3
     0     2     1     0     0     0
     0     5     0     8     7     0
     0     9    10     3     1     2
mask =
     0     0     0     0     1     1
     0     1     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1
valid =
     0     1     0     1     1     0
idx =
     1     2     1     3     3     1
out =
     0     2     0     3     3     0
```

---

**Generic case**

For generic case of minimum N consecutive non-zeros case, you can use `2D convolution` with a kernel as a column vectors of `N` ones, like so -

```
mask = A~=0  %// Mask of non-zeros in input, A

%// Find starting row indices alongwith boolean valid flags for minimum N 
%// consecutive nonzeros in each column
[valid,idx] = max(conv2(double(mask),ones(N,1),'valid')==N,[],1)

%// Use the valid flags to set invalid row indices to zeros
out = idx.*valid
```

Please note that the 2D convolution could be replaced by a separable convolution version as mentioned in the comments by Luis and that seems to be a bit faster. More info on this could be accessed at this [`link`](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/). So,

`conv2(double(mask),ones(N,1),'valid')` could be replaced by `conv2(ones(N,1),1,double(mask),'valid')`.

Sample run -

```
A =
     0     0     0     0     0     3
     0     2     1     0     1     2
     0     5     0     8     7     9
     0     9     0     3     1     2
mask =
     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     1     1     0     1     1
     0     1     0     1     1     1
     0     1     0     1     1     1
N =
     3
valid =
     0     1     0     0     1     1
idx =
     1     2     1     1     2     1
out =
     0     2     0     0     2     1
```

Comment: Thank you again, it works. I will have to play with the minimum consecutive values threshold.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, to be able to make N dynamic. I appreciate your help. Cheers.

Comment: Generalization with `conv2` is awesome :) already added my vote :P

Comment: You could save some time using the [separable](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/) version of `conv2`: `conv2(ones(N,1),1,double(mask),'valid')`. Even if the kernel is a single column, explicitly calling the separable version seems to be faster on my machine

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you so much, very useful that info! Seems to be  faster at my end too. Added into the solution.